Flutter media_kit Unexpected position change
I am using media_kit for HLS video streaming, but I'm facing an issue where, if there’s an error from the server (e.g., HTTP error 500 Internal Server Error), media_kit sometimes skips to the next .ts segment rather than waiting to retry or fetch the missing .ts file. How can I configure it to handle errors without skipping to the next segment?
